# Applying boundary conditins to a differential equation confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

[image]

Here $k, A_1, A_2$ are constants

Although $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx \not\equiv 0$, $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx$ can equal zero at certain values of $x$

For example if $A_1=1, A_2=1, k=1$ then

cos$x$+sin$x=0$ at $x=-\pi/4$, so is the conclusion of this solution incorrect? i.e

Is the solution:

$w^2=gk$tanh$(kh)$ $\cup$ $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require

$$-w^2\phi + g\phi_y = 0$$
$$(-w^2\cosh kh + gk\sinh kh)(A_1\cos kx + A_2\sin kx) =0$$

where it appears $g$ is a constant.

We don't want the solution to be identically zero. Note if $A_1 = A_2 = 0$, then $\phi \equiv0$ regardless of $x,y$. It's okay for $\phi(x,y) = 0$ for certain $(x,y)$, though. If you replace the word "zero" with "identically zero," your notes seem to make sense.

So if $\phi$ is not identically zero, how do we satisfy the requirement? Well where ever $\phi$ is nonzero in $x$, we can divide to get

$$(-w^2\cosh kh + gk\sinh kh) =0$$
$$w^2=gk\tanh(kh)$$

So why not say:

$w^2=gk\tanh(kh) ∪ A_1\cos kx+A_2\sin kx=0?$

Well, we were possibly going to get the latter part equal to zero at *some points*, so we don't really have to mention it in the solution. Those points already satisfied the requirement $-w^2\phi + g\phi_y = 0$. To make sure the requirement stays intact for all points in a nontrivial way, we just have to make sure $w^2=gk\tanh(kh)$.

Comment: Also note that either $A_1$ or $A_2$ (but not both) can equal zero, depending on boundary conditions. You'll still have a solution.

Comment: I have edited the OP to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: See new response. Let me know if this addressed the question.